# My Galaxy SIII Screen auto wake up

Tags: screen, task-management

My Galaxy SIII display screens auto wake up (Lights Up) for no reason. I have tried with Factory Reset but does not work. Also Task Manager Pop up window auto displays and after that my power button does not respond. While after next auto screen off (mine is 15 Secs) power button works smoothly. One thing also Home button completely become unresponsive after 1-2 min of phone restart. Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Some app might be triggering the phone to wake up.
Did you check if there any app holding screen wakelock with Wakelock Detector?

[play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector)